# Unclassifiable statement in fortran using matrix

Tags: fortran

This is the part of the code that gives me problems:

```
      PROGRAM concept
      IMPLICIT NONE
      REAL, DIMENSION (3,7) :: datin
      REAL, DIMENSION (2,4) :: datiel
      REAL, DIMENSION (4,4) :: ke1
      REAL :: c1, c2
      WRITE (*,*)   "Inserire il valore di alpha per il primo elemento"
      READ (*,*)    datiel(1,1)
      WRITE (*,*)   "alpha1=", datiel(1,1)
      WRITE (*,*)   "alpha2=", datiel(2,1)
      c1=(datiel(1,2))*(datiel(1,3))/(datin(2,1)-datin(1,1))
      ke1(1,1)=c1*(cosd(datiel(1,1)))^2
      ke1(1,2)=c1*(sind(datiel(1,1)))*(cosd(datiel(1,1)))
      ke1(1,3)=c1*(-(cosd(datiel(1,1)))^2)
      ke1(1,4)=c1*(-sind(datiel(1,1)))*(cosd(datiel(1,1)))
      ke1(2,1)=ke1(1,2)
      ke1(2,2)=c1*(sind(datiel(1,1)))^2
      ke1(2,3)=ke1(1,4)
      ke1(2,4)=c1*(-(sind(datiel(1,1)))^2)
      ke1(3,1)=ke1(1,3)
      ke1(3,2)=ke1(2,3)
      ke1(3,3)=ke1(1,1)
      ke1(3,4)=ke1(1,2)
      ke1(4,1)=ke1(1,4)
      ke1(4,2)=ke1(2,4)
      ke1(4,3)=ke1(3,4)
      ke1(4,4)=ke1(2,2)
      END PROGRAM
```

When compiling it gives:

[image]

I am using a macbook.
I am trying to figure out why it doesn't work, but some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks a bit like a problem with fixed formatted code, are the first 6 characters on every line spaces?

Comment: Hello, please copy-paste as text the full error log. Sometimes the last line of it matters, sometimes the first. At the same time, remove the screenshot please.

Comment: Welcome. Do *not* post errors as a picture. *Always* copy them as a text. It is really really important. The errors *must* be searchable. Please take the [tour] and read what the dialog box said when you were uploading the picture. It said you should not use it to post code or error outputs.

Comment: As indicated by @albert, you have a problem with your syntax. The `^` should be replaced by `**`. Also, since you use the functions `sind` and `cosd`, you have to enable them using the `-fdec-math` compiler flag of `gfortran`. However, they are compiler extensions, so it is always a better practice to convert them to the default `sin` and `cos` and convert the degrees to radians first.

Comment: As a stand alone Program, the arrays datiel and datin are being used without being given an initial value, eg "WRITE (*,*)   "alpha2=", datiel(2,1)" and "c1=(datiel(1,2))*(datiel(1,3))/(datin(2,1)-datin(1,1))" . This needs to be addressed. I must admit I find "^2" an attractive Fortran extension although I have not seen it implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of problems in your code:

- power in Fortran isn't `^` but `**`
- `sind` and `cosd` should be replaced by `sin` and `cos` as the later are standard functions and the versions with the `d` are extensions. Based on the comment from @kvantour, @evets : Note: `sind` and `cosd` are DEC Fortran compiler / gnu compiler extensions which compute the sine and cosine of an angle given in degrees, so some conversion of the argument has to be done as well!

Comment: `sind` and `cosd` are gnu compiler extensions which compute the sine and cosine of an angle given in degrees. You were probably thinking about the `dsin` and `dcos` functions. I agree that they are bad practice, but just replacing them with `sin` and `cos` will create a different behaviour of the code.

Comment: Already found the problem with sind and cosd, but I missed that little particular on exponentiation.... THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: @kvantour thanks for the hint / corection, I was indeed thinking about `dsin` and `dcos`.

Comment: @LucaDomenighini If this answer helped you out, don't forget to thank the person by having upvoting and/or accepting the answer to be valid. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @kvantour, `sind` and `cosd` are DEC Fortran compiler extension, which happen to be support by GNU Fortran.  A bigger problem with the code is likely the `read` statement, which reads a single element into the array.  OP may need to change that to `read(*,*) datiel`; otherwise, most of the elements of `datiel` are undefined.

Comment: @evets that is probably the next question from OP, but the main problem was the compilation.